# Why is VkSubpassDependency needed?

Tags: vulkan

In the code:

```
vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphore, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);
```

We pass a semaphore that will tell us when the image is available, but we expect it only at VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT:

```
VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphore };
VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;
```

It's also not clear, if I have multiple pipelines, then wait during each stage VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT in each pipeline?
Before our sub-pass and before VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT we have not yet received the image and it means that the "implicit" sub-pass before our sub-pass was called when no image was received yet. I understood the essence of the problem and understood the solution with adding VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT to submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask, so that the pipeline is not started at all before receiving the image. But there is another solution using VkSubpassDependency. I don't see how this solves the problem with the "implicit" subpass starting early:

```
VkSubpassDependency dependency{};
dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
```

But here in dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT we only specified that dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT cannot start before dependency.srcStageMask, but it is the same stage! How is this supposed to help prevent an "implicit" sub-pass from starting? Maybe the implicit subpass has its own pipeline, which is what translates my image from VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL. Even so, by the code dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT we are not restricting it to run in any way! I'm confused help me

I tried searching for information online, but there was no detailed explanation anywhere.

Comment: The only object in Vulkan with `pWaitDstStageMask` is the semaphore wait part of a `VkSubmitInfo`. So... what does that have to do with anything? What does that semaphore represent? What are you trying to use this dependency to do?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I edited the question, I think it made more sense.

Comment: This question seems decidedly confused about certain concepts. There is no "'implicit' sub-pass", and pipeline *objects* do not have dependencies. Dependencies are a function of command execution, not pipeline objects. Also, you haven't shown the entire code for the subpass dependency, particularly the layout setup that is at the heart of all of this.